# Organic Nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

10.2 It has to add 4-propyl is that correct? And 10.3 why do we choose the position 1,5 instead of 2,3?[image]

[image]

Comment: And 10.4,, it should be included the stereochemistry of the middle double bond in front of the name as ($3E$)-3,4-diethyl...., to complete IUPAC name.

Comment: Actually, none of the suggested names is in accordance with current IUPAC recommendations.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are correct in 10.2 and in 10.3 it should be 3-ethyl-2-methyl cyclopent-1-ene. This is to give the lowest locant to double bond.